# UWP - How to check if in-app products were bought previously?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a WinRT app that makes use of the Windows Phone Store to create in-app purchases. Once the user bought the durable in-app purchase, a boolean in the app settings will be set to true.

Now if the user uninstall the app, and re-installs it the boolean will be set to false obviously. The user can then go to the in-app purchase and buy it again: however, the Store will indicate that the user already bought this in-app purchase and it can install it again without additional costs.

Now - is it possible to get a list of in-app purchases that the user already bought, so I can enable the features by default (without having the user go to the purchase page again)?

Niels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`LicenseInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.store.licenseinformation.aspx) object you can directly check if an In-App Purchase has been made by that user. See [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Dn532254(v=win.10).aspx) for details, specifically the "Code the feature in a conditional block" section. In general, it is:

```
CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses["IAPKey"].IsActive
```